# Programaticly positioning UI elements in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've just started with Xamarin and I'm having great difficulty programmatically placing UI elements exactly where I want them.

Currently I'm using this sort of method:

```
            Label AppTitle = new Label
        {
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = "FishBike GPS"
        };
        Button MenuButton = new Button
        {
            Image = "images/hamburger_icon.bmp",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
        };

        Title = "FishBike GPS";

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                    AppTitle,
                    MenuButton
                }
        };
```

However this leaves a lot to be desired. For one thing, I really want the label and button to be on the same 'line' as it were. However this puts them one under the other. I'd really like to also have more choice exactly how far to the left / right the label appears.

While I'm here can anyone tell me how to set an image for the button. I need it to display a hamburger menu icon. (something that looks like an equals but with an extra line in the middle) however I am struggling to implement this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain elements one near other, and I think it is must be horizontly, than use orientation property of StackLayout. Set it "Horizontal" and you will have what you want. Also you can use another layout like Relative. 
Now about hamburger. In Xamarin.Forms does'n exist button with image. But it is in https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton . There are another good things too. Or you can use Gestures in Xamarin.Forms
You can't put button in action bar or toolbar. In Xamarin.Forms it must be only toolbar element. But you can use AppCompat : https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/ . Few month ago I spent much time to figure it out. So, read and try more and more and you will catch this.